# Offline HTML5 apps and cross-site communication

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, local-storage, browser-cache

I am working on a web application that works in the browser offline using Cache Manifests/HTML5. In some instances, a modified version of the application may run on another server or domain. If these two web applications want to communicate **while offline**, how could they accomplish this?

As far as I know, there is no global-storage method like there is local-storage. AJAX won't work, as that has to do with server-side scripting. Websites can only assign cookies to their domain, etc.

Does the user have to be online in order for communication between the two cross-site web-apps?

Comment: I'm still new to SE, and just realized... Should this be Programmers instead of SO?

Comment: No, this seems like a good place for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the 2nd application in an iframe and communicate with it with `window.postMessage()`.

Comment: Thanks! HTML5 has so many new features... I haven't had time to test it, but this looks very doable!

Answer (score 1):

you could store the data in localStorage while offline, then save it to the server when the user comes back online. Here's a simple demo: https://github.com/chovy/offline-app

Comment: That looks like a wonderful script for learning how to make a simple offline application, but the problem I posted above is not related to that. Is the question I posted confusing? What can I do to clarify my problem?

Comment: you need a network connection to communicate w/ anything else online.